# Rewrite /(index.php) to /home/(index.php)

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite `www.example.com` or `www.example.com/` or `www.example.com/index.php` to `/home/`.

I tried this but I'm getting `Internal Server Error`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/$1 [L]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try below rule,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/|/index.php)$
RewriteRule ^ home/ [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule as your very first rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteEngine ^/?(index\.php)?$ /home/ [L,NC]
```